# Eigen::SPQR module complains about rows mismatch when solving using least-squares

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen, suitesparse

I am using `Eigen::SPQR` module to solve a least-squares problem `Ax = b`, and I am getting an error complaining about rows mismatch at the solve step. In general my code consists of initializing A using triplets, b using bracket operators and then computing QR decomposition and finally solving.

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A;
// Fill A using triplets

Eigen::VectorXd b(A.rows()); 
// Fill b using square bracket operator b[i] = ...

Eigen::SPQR< Eigen::SparseMatrix < double > > QR(A);

Eigen::VectorXd X = QR.solve(b); // Line giving error.
```

Vector b was created with size equal to `A.rows()` so I am sure it is correct. However, when I check the function `QR.rows()` it returns the value of `A.cols()`. Is this some kind of bug? I checked that `Eigen::SparseQR` solves it without errors but it is a lot slower, so I would like to use the `SuiteSparse` module instead. Any ideas?

Comment: This is odd, as Eigen's unit tests are running on rectangular matrices too. Make sure you are using latest releases (3.2.10 or 3.3-rc1).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using Eigen 3.2.10. Maybe I should move to 3.3-rc1 ? Or it wouldn't make any difference?

Comment: I tested 3.3-rc1. Same error. And only using the SuiteSparse  Eigen::SPQR module. The Eigen::SparseQR works fine.

Comment: You are right, this is now fixed in 3.2 and 3.3 branches.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I download a version with this problem fixed?

Comment: See this (link)[https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/downloads?tab=branches].